# Failed login attempts

Tags: users, security

I'm using WordFence for site monitoring and overall security. I'm seeing some failed login  attempts from a couple of different locations with username "admin" and "companyname". I'm not familiar with the IP addresses or who they belong to.

My question is, would this prompt you to block the IP addresses? Also, should I consider blocking the login page from all IP address except for ones that are approved?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it but I think you could use this plugin
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ban/

that should solve these issues

Comment: I can actually ban IP addresses with Wordfence or at the server level. I'm also wondering if it might be better to ban at the server level rather than just Wordfence?

Comment: server level ip blocking is always better

Comment: Would this type of behavior prompt you to block the IP address?

Comment: no yo ushould do this manually.

Comment: Yes, I don't want to rely on a plugin to automatically block IP addresses. That is too risky.

Comment: I think, I might be wrong, that blocking IP addresses is a manual process. of course yo ucan block IP adresses which have failed login attempts

Comment: I think your suggestion of blocking the login page from *all* IPs except those approved would be the most efficient.